# PreparedStatement does not work with MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am new to java web.I want to write simple login page that insert data to MySql.When I run the code everything runs okay,but data int inserted to database.I searched about 2 days now but can not solve it.Thanks for any help
First is my database class name is MyDb and second one is server.Also my id is auto-increment

```
#1
Connection conn;
public Connection getCon(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sign_up", "root", "12345");
        System.out.println("connection is done");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return conn;
}
#2
public class registr extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String username = request.getParameter("username")
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        MyDb db = new MyDb();
        Connection conn = db.getCon();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        String query = "INSERT INTO sign(name, surname, email, password)" + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        stmt.setString(2, username);
        stmt.setString(3, password);
        stmt.setString(4, email);
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(registr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Comment: There is no error code

Answer (score 0):

Change  `stmt.executeUpdate(query)`; to  `stmt.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 0):

If you have posted all of the Servlet class code, then you're missing something. The official Servlet interface does not call the `processRequest` method automatically. Here is an extract of the JavaDoc for the HttpServlet:

> public abstract class HttpServlet extends GenericServlet implements java.io.Serializable
>
> Provides an abstract class to be subclassed to create an HTTP servlet suitable for a Web site. A subclass of HttpServlet must override at least one method, usually one of these:

```
doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
doPost, for HTTP POST requests
doPut, for HTTP PUT requests
doDelete, for HTTP DELETE requests
init and destroy, to manage resources that are held for the life of the servlet
getServletInfo, which the servlet uses to provide information about itself
```

> There's almost no reason to override the service method. service handles standard HTTP requests by dispatching them to the handler methods for each HTTP request type (the doXXX methods listed above).

So what you have to do is, to change your Servlet, for example, as follows

```
public class registr extends HttpServlet {
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws  ServletException, IOException {
         processRequest(req, res);
     }
     
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws  ServletException, IOException {
         processRequest(req, res);
     }
     
     protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     {
         // your code
     } 

}
```

Tip: Java coding convetion states that the name of your classes should start a capital letter, i.e., instead of `registr` it should be `Registr`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understood